# Why is an enum declared in a separate file, in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Why is this enum declared in its own file. Is there an advantage to this? Also how would I be able to put this in one of the 2 files. I really have no clue what I am doing. Please also explain this in a simple way, since this is a textbook example, and I am fairly new to Java.

ScaleName.java

```
enum ScaleName {celsius, fahrenheit, kelvin, rankine};
```

Temperature.java

```
class Temperature {

    private double number;
    private ScaleName scale;

    public Temperature() {
        number = 0.0;
        scale = ScaleName.fahrenheit;
    }

    public Temperature(double number) {
        this.number = number;
        scale = ScaleName.fahrenheit;
    }

    public Temperature(ScaleName scale) {
        number = 0.0;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public Temperature(double number, ScaleName scale) {
        this.number = number;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public void setNumber(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public double getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setScale(ScaleName scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public ScaleName getScale() {
        return scale;
    }
}
```

UseTemperature.java

```
class Temperature {

    private double number;
    private ScaleName scale;

    public Temperature() {
        number = 0.0;
        scale = ScaleName.fahrenheit;
    }

    public Temperature(double number) {
        this.number = number;
        scale = ScaleName.fahrenheit;
    }

    public Temperature(ScaleName scale) {
        number = 0.0;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public Temperature(double number, ScaleName scale) {
        this.number = number;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public void setNumber(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public double getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setScale(ScaleName scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public ScaleName getScale() {
        return scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [*Enums*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Why is an enum declared in a separate file, in Java?

You don't *have to* declare an `enum` in a separate file.  You could do this:

```
public class Temperature {
    public enum ScaleName {celsius, fahrenheit, kelvin, rankine};
    
    private double number;
    private ScaleName scale;

    public Temperature() {
        number = 0.0;
        scale = ScaleName.fahrenheit;
    }
    ...
}
```

The only difference between this and making the enum a top level class is that you now need to *qualify* the name of the enum when you use it in a different class.

But what is going on *in my example* is no different to what happens if the enum was any other static nested class.  (A nested enum is implicitly static, so we don't need a `static` keyword.  See [JLS 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).)

---

> Why is this enum declared in its own file.

Because the code author chose to do it this way<sup>1</sup>.

> Is there an advantage to this?

Yes. It means that don't have to qualify the `enum` to use it ... in some circumstances where you would have to if the `enum` was nested as above.

---

Actually, Java does allow you to put multiple top-level classes into the same source file *provided that* all but one of the classes is "package private".  However, doing that is generally thought to be bad style, and it can be problematic for some tool chains ... I have heard.

---

<sup>1 - If you want to know the *real* reason why the authors of the textbook chose to do it that way, you would need to ask them!</sup>

Answer (score 20):

Enums are not just bare values in Java, they are much more than that. They are classes in their own right (they inherit `Object`). And consider these:

```
public enum Int {
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2);

    private final int value;

    Int(final int value) { this.value = value; }

    public int getValue() { return value; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "I am integer " + value; }
}
```

Consider also:

```
public enum Operation
{
    PLUS
        {
            @Override
            public int calculate(final int i1, final int i2)
            {
                return i1 + i2; 
            }
        };

    public abstract int calculate(int i1, int i2);
}

final int ret = Operation.PLUS.calculate(2, 3);
```

And you can combine them both, too. They are very powerful tools.

Comment: I am sure that this is a great answer, and makes sense, to somebody more advanced then I. However your code is much more complicated then the syntax that I know so far. I am learning, not an expert.

Comment: You can equally use simple enums: `public enum Const { VALUE1, VALUE2 }`. But the thing is, they are classes (with some pecularities), so they are used as such ;)

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 5):

An `enum` is a `class` and follows same regulations.

Having it on its own file is exactly like moving an inner class in a separate file, nothing more nor less. So yes you can move it inside one of the class and be able to access it from outside with `OuterClass.ScaleName` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an enum in its own file in case I needed to use that enum in multiple different locations throughout my project. You could define the enum for each file you wanted to use it in, but then if you needed to update the enum, you would have to update it in each file. If you define in once and need to update it, you only need to update it the one time. This is not only easier but also ensures you don't miss one of the enum definitions throughout your codebase.