# I can't make a enum file in intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I am making a project in IntelliJ and I wanted to make an enum file but I couldn't find it. Has the enum file been replaced with another file or am I just stupid?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "enum file". What language are you using? Java? And what are you trying to achieve? Create an `enum`?

Comment: So I am trying to get an Enum class in my java project in intelij and normaly you can just create an enum class but now I can't

Comment: what does "now I can't" mean? What exactly stops you from creating a .java file? Just create a regular new java class, then replace `class` with `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

If by 'enum file', you mean an enum class, It will be created just as any other class, except that you use word 'enum' instead of 'class'.
File -> New -> Java class.
After clicking on Java class, select enum type.

see this link for more help:
[Why is an enum declared in a separate file, in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431472/why-is-an-enum-declared-in-a-separate-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can define an enum in Java by any of three ways:

- In a separate `.java` file as shown in [this other correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70454885/642706) by Yazdani.
- Nested within another class.
- Locally, within a method. 
  (As of Java 16+, see [*Java JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).)

IntelliJ supports all three.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest that you should reinstall IntelliJ Idea IDE.
2. Use the latest version of IntelliJ idea.